# Is spawning threads based on application memory usage an overkill?

Tags: multithreading, memory, spawn, overhead

I have a system that uses threads to do various jobs.

Each thread uses from enough to too much memory, so there are times that the PC gets out of memory.

Each thread works from 8sec to 40sec max. approximatelly.

Is using Process.WorkingSet64 before spawing a new thread (to check for memory usage) an overkill ?

Basically, I am trying to prevent out-of-memory situations.

Is using Process.WorkingSet64 too heavy for calling it that often (let's say once every 4 seconds)?

Comment: You are running out of memory on a 64-bit system?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the computer is running out of memory when some threads all use more than ~3GB. I have seen threads using up to 5GB.